# Why does executing this shell script shut down my system?

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, gnome-terminal, shutdown

Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS

Was trying to install Pycharm without using snap.

I navigated to the bin folder and then:

```
chmod u+x pycharm.sh
```

followed by:

```
sh pycharm.sh
```

My system instantly shut down within seconds.

[This is the page I got the instructions from](https://itsfoss.com/install-pycharm-ubuntu/)

Comment: To answer this, we need to know the contents of the script `pycharm.sh` - please provide this info.

Comment: Interesting. I downloaded the `pycharm.sh` script. It doesn't contain anything like `shutdown` or `reboot`, but it would be useful to know how far it gets. Please insert lots of debugging commands into the script (`echo "Debug 1"`, `echo "Debug 2"` etc. ), then execute the script while redirecting the output to a file, that you then can consult after rebooting.